# How to delete all files and folders with named exceptions with PHP or any other command

Tags: command-line, php

I want to remove all files and dirs except for certain files whose names I want to specify. Is there any PHP script that can help me?

Here is an example:

Dir name:

```
/home/root/database/
```

files in "database" dir are:

```
  [include]
   [img]
  [file]
  index.php
  index.html
 .htaccess
 index.jpg
 index.png
  readme.txt
  video.mp4
  music.mp3
```

I want to remove all files except `.htaccess` and `index.php` and the `[file]` dir.

Is there any command that can save these files and remove the other files or any php code?

Comment: Is PHP even capable of deleting files? What’s the reason you’re mentioning a PHP script?

Comment: Do you have command line access to this account?

Answer (score 4):

**Command line**

First make a copy of all:

```
tar -cf /to/a/save/place/PHP_backup.tar *
```

where /to/a/save/place is any directory not in that path.

Now you can use the following command:

```
rm -rv !(.htaccess|index.php|file)
```

**delete files from php**

If you have to use php, you can take this [funtion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338133/9008235) and modify it to leave the wanted files and dir.

Comment: Why not just `tar -cf /ta/a/safe/place/backup.tar *` in the first place? Extended pattern matching operators like `!(…)` need the `extglob` shell option enabled, which it may not be by default (test for that with `bash -O|grep extglob`) – run `shopt -s extglob` to enable it.

Comment: yes of course! ;) forgot

Comment: @dessert checked bash -O , is off , and it works too?

Comment: You misunderstood me, `bash -O` shows what is the default on your system, without reading `.bashrc` and the like, to show your current setting run `shopt extglob` (without `-s`).

Comment: Did you mean `rm -rv` or rather `rm -rf`?

Comment: @dessert you are right!  every day bash surprise me with another feature.

Answer (score 2):

the `trash` command from [trash-cli](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=trash-cli) is very handy for this type of thing. It's available in the universe repository and you can install it if you don't have it with the command `sudo apt install trash-cli`

Once installed you can simply issue the command

`trash !(.htaccess|index.php|file)` which tells it to trash everything not matching what is in the parenthesis. In this case .htaccess , index.php and the directory file.

Of course this requires extended pattern matching to be turned on with `shopt -s extglob` as mentioned by [dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) in this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054639/how-to-remove-all-files-and-folders-expect-some-files-using-php-or-any-other-com/1054650#comment1724506_1054645)

There really is no need to backup everything in a tar file with this approach as everything you trash will be in the trash bin and if you make a mistake you can recover with `restore-trash` and selecting the corresponding file or directory that you wish to restore.

If you must have PHP see [unlink.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

This answer was inspired in part by [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1054645/225694)